# Understanding the defining polynomial of the finite field $F_{p^d}$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I came across the following in my Cryptography notes:

Definition: Let $p$ denote a prime number, and let $F_p$ denote the field with $p$ elements. Let $f(x)$ denote an irreducible polynomial over $F_p$ of degree $d$. The finite field $F_{p^d}$ with $p^d$ elements, is simply the quotient ring:

$F_{p^d} = F_p[x]/(f) = \{ \sum_{i=0}^{d-1}a_ix^i ; a_i \in F_p$ and $f=0 \}$.
The polynomial $f(x)$ is called the defining polynomial of the finite field $F_{p^d}$.

From my understand of ring theory, $F_p[x]/(f) = \{p(x) + (f)|p(x) \in F_p[x] \}$, so I am not sure how this definition was arrived at. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Use polynomial long division.

Comment: As @enedil suggests, you represent each coset $C$ as in your abstract definition by the remainder upon division by $f$ of *any* element of $C$. You need to check that different elements of $C$ yield the same remainder, of course: an instructive exercise.

Comment: A known field extension is $\Bbb C=\Bbb R(i)$ where we *adjoin* a new 'indeterminate' $i$ *that satisfies* $i^2+1=0$. So, $\Bbb C\cong\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$. All finite dimensional field extensions can be thought similarly.

Comment: @Lubin, what I'm not sure about now is the statement $f = 0$ in my first definition of $F_{p^d}$

Comment: Well, note that every element of $\Bbb F_{p^d}$ is represented by a polynomial expression in $x$ of degree $<d$. But since $f$ is in the zero-coset, if you write down $f(x)$, you get $f(x)=0$ in your field. Said in a different way, when you divide $f$ by $f$ to get a remainder of degree less than that of $f$, that remainder is zero.

Comment: @Lubin ok I understand now, thanks for the help.